# Distributing application with its Maven POM only

Tags: java, maven

Is it possible to distribute my application with its POM only ?

I have deployed my application in a remote repository and I think it would be nice if I can distribute only its POM, instead of asking the users to download the complete source first and use the POM to build the application afterwards. 
The idea is that users would be able to install the application using the POM and a single Maven command.

I tried adding to the POM a `downloadURL` in a `distributionManagement` section without success. Here my experiment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>aGroupId</groupId>
<artifactId>anArtifactId</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>

<distributionManagement>
    <downloadUrl>anURL</downloadUrl>
</distributionManagement>

<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>someId</id>
      <url>anURL</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
</project>
```

Thanks in advance for any feedback

Comment: This question doesn't make a lot of sense. What good does it do to someone to just get your POM, and not the JAR/EAR/whatever that it describes? If you've deployed to a "remote repository," don't the potential users have access to that repository? And if they don't, how do they use your application?

Comment: hi @kdgregory. I just wondered if I can distribute the POM in places other than the remote repository (like my web page or something like that). I have not seen this so probably it is not possible, but I wanted to confirm that is the case.

Comment: You can distribute the POM anyplace you like. But it won't do anyone any good.

Comment: not sure if we are talking about the same. I do know users need access to my jar, that is in the repository. My question is if the users can obtain this jar just with its POM and executing a single Maven command. And if this is possible, how should I configure such POM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're distributing source, then you should look at the bootstrap POM method: http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/examples/bootstrapping-with-pom.html

where the 'scm' element is key.  The user has only to run scm:bootstrap to then receive the project source tree from which to build the project.

-tim

Comment: thanks @tdrury, that is what I wanted to know. Just for curiosity, in an scenario where I do not want to distribute the sources, but only the packaged binary jar and its dependencies, which Maven command should I use ? (in case such thing is possible). Thanks for any pointer in case you have a clue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`dependency:get`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html) mojo to download an artifact to a specified location:

```
mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=<groupid>:<artifactid>:<version> /
 -Ddest=path/to/destination.jar
```